# How can I add html element with string interpolation in angular?

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, angular6, string-interpolation

How can I add a html element dynamically using string interpolation **without add any html tag**? Exp:

This is my obj in my component

```
myObj = {
    title: 'Header Title',
    icon: '<i class="fa fa-user">'
}
```

I want to add this like;

```
<header>
    {{myObj.title}} - {{myObj.icon}}
</header>
```

{{myObj.icon}} rendered as text, but I want render as html. How can?

I want the result to be as follows

```
<header>
    Header Title <i class ="fa fa-user"></i>
</header>
```

and if I change my obj like this;

```
myObj = {
    title: 'Header Title',
    icon: '<mat-icon>search</mat-icon>'
}
```

render as

```
<header>
    Header Title <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
</header>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Try: `<header [innerHTML]="myObj.title + ' - ' + myObj.icon">`. I don't know if it works for the `i` tag however.

Answer (score 6):

### You can leverage innerHTML

```
<header>
    <span>{{myObj.title}}</span> - <span [innerHTML]="myObj.icon"></span>
</header>
```

> Note : I have used  to segregated the elements however you can pick any element as per your design.

Comment: thanks but i want to make it without adding any html tag as span

Comment: Use DomSanitizer or DomSanitizationService

Comment: @SunilSingh could you give us an example usage of `DomSanitizer` in this context?